# Intersection observer causing infinite loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, intersection-observer

I'm trying to observe 3 elements coming into view and updating state each time one of them comes into view.

I've tried several approaches including other libraries, useMemo, useCallback, refs, etc... My most recent code is:

## Infinite loop example

This happens because in the useEffect the observer fires and invokes `updateAssets()` which causes a re-render which then I think creates a new observer and starts the infinite loop.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import useMeasure from 'react-use-measure';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import { RenderPropSticky } from 'react-sticky-el';
import { SxProps } from '@mui/system';
import { Wrapper } from 'src/containers';
import { Spacer, Box, Column } from 'src/components-v2/Layout';
import { Typography } from 'src/components-v2/DataDisplay';
import { Image } from 'src/components-v2/Media';

const items = [
  { id: nanoid(), src: 'https://picsum.photos/546/503', isVisible: false },
  { id: nanoid(), src: 'https://picsum.photos/546/503', isVisible: false },
  { id: nanoid(), src: 'https://picsum.photos/546/503', isVisible: false },
];

interface IStepperProps {
  sx?: SxProps;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Stepper: React.FunctionComponent<IStepperProps> = ({ sx, children }) => {
  const [assets, updateAssets] = React.useState(items);
  console.log('assets: ', assets);
  const [assetRef, assetRefBounds] = useMeasure();

  const callback = (entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        const newAssets = assets.map((asset) => {
          if (entry.target.id === asset.id) {
            return { ...asset, isVisible: entry.isIntersecting };
          }
          return { ...asset, isVisible: false };
        });
        updateAssets(newAssets);
      }
    });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.step');
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, { rootMargin: '0px' });
    nodes.forEach((node) => {
      observer.observe(node);
    });
    return () => {
      nodes.forEach((node) => {
        observer.unobserve(node);
      });
    };
  });

  return (
    <Wrapper sx={sx} className='stepper'>
      <Column lgOffset={2} lg={20}>
        {children}
      </Column>
      <Column lgOffset={2} lg={1} sx={{ borderRight: 'solid 1px white' }}>
        {/* <Bullet /> */}
      </Column>
      <Column lgOffset={1} lg={7} sx={{}}>
        <Spacer height={200} />
        {assets.map((asset, index) => {
          return (
            <Box key={`step-${nanoid()}`} id={asset.id} className='step'>
              <Spacer height={48} />
              <Typography variant='h6' sx={{ color: 'white', mb: '32px' }}>
                lorem ipsum
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant='p' sx={{ color: 'white' }}>
                lorem ipsum
              </Typography>
              <Spacer height={62} />
              <Typography variant='h5' sx={{ color: 'white' }}>
                <b>
                  Speed up onboarding by
                  <br />
                  as much as
                </b>
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant='h1' sx={{ color: 'white ' }}>
                20%
              </Typography>
              <Spacer height={index === assets.length - 1 ? 200 : 100} />
            </Box>
          );
        })}
      </Column>
      <Column lgOffset={1} lg={10} sx={{}}>
        <RenderPropSticky boundaryElement='.stepper' bottomOffset={100}>
          {({
            isFixed,
            wrapperStyles,
            wrapperRef,
            holderStyles,
            holderRef,
          }) => {
            return (
              <div ref={holderRef} style={holderStyles}>
                <div style={wrapperStyles} ref={wrapperRef}>
                  <Spacer
                    sx={{
                      height: `calc((100vh - ${assetRefBounds.height}px) / 2)`,
                    }}
                  />
                  <Image
                    alt='placeholder'
                    height='503'
                    ref={assetRef}
                    src={
                      assets.find((asset) => {
                        return !!asset.isVisible;
                      })?.src || ''
                    }
                    sx={{ display: 'block', margin: '0 auto' }}
                    width='546'
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </RenderPropSticky>
      </Column>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Stepper;
```

## With dependency array

When I add `assets` to the dependency array and I don't receive any updates because the useEffect only fires on mount and there is nothing to invoke `updateAssets()` after that.

```
const callback = React.useCallback(
    (entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          const newAssets = assets.map((asset) => {
            if (entry.target.id === asset.id) {
              return { ...asset, isVisible: entry.isIntersecting };
            }
            return { ...asset, isVisible: false };
          });
          updateAssets(newAssets);
        }
      });
    },
    [assets],
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.step');
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, { rootMargin: '0px' });
    nodes.forEach((node) => {
      observer.observe(node);
    });
    return () => {
      nodes.forEach((node) => {
        observer.unobserve(node);
      });
    };
  }, [assets, callback]);
```

I've been fighting with this all day and can't seem to be able to find a solution. And yes I know I'm not using refs. I was, but I change because I'm running out of options.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

So it turns out I just needed to check if an asset was marked as visible to prevent another update

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // TODO: switch to refs
    const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.step');
    const options = {
      rootMargin: `0px 0px 0px 0px`,
      threshold: 1.0,
    };
    // TODO: maybe move callback?
    const callback = (entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        const asset = assets.find((asset) => {
          return asset.id === entry.target.id;
        });
        if (entry.isIntersecting && !asset.isVisible) { <-- FIXES LOOP 
          updateState(entry.target.id);
        }
      });
    };
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
    nodes.forEach((node) => {
      observer.observe(node);
    });
    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
    };
  });
```